# Java and Spring implement transactional function

Tags: java, transactions, spring-3

I'm using java 1.6 and spring 3.0.4, I want to realize a java functionality that

- calculate new data values
- update one-by-one the existing values on the database

If in any of this step there's an error I want to rollback the whole transaction and come back to the previous state.

I already realized all this pieces of code, I just want to put them together. How I can manage this with the existing spring values that are working with `@Entity` and `@Column` annotations?

Thanks!

Comment: A whole chapter of the Spring documentation is dedicated to transactions. Read it: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that need the same configuration, here you can find how I solved this problem, integrating Hibernate with Spring.

```
<!-- session factory activate the transaction modules for the specified classes -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource">
  <ref bean="dataSource" />
</property>
<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:config-hibernate.xml" />
<property name="packagesToScan">
  <list>
    <!-- Additional packages required to be added if entities located elsewhere -->
    <value>com.some.package.dao</value>
    <value>com.some.package.model</value>
    <value>com.some.package.SpecificClass</value>
  </list>
</property>
<property name="mappingResources" ref="mappingResources"/>
```

```
<bean id="mappingResources" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean">
<property name="sourceList">
  <list>
    <!-- here you can add your hibernate mapping query that you want to use on transaction -->
    <value>config-hibernate-mapping.xml</value>
  </list>
 </property>
</bean>

<!-- This will activate transactional annotation -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SpecificClass {
  // write your method, everyone of them will be transactional
  // and there will be  a commit in case of success or rollback in case of exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: as you're using Spring, the easiest would be to use [the transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), creating a service that represents this transaction unit and annotate the method with `@Transactional`

In practice, you need to configure a `PlatformTransactionManager` in your application. As you seem to use JPA, the `JpaTransationManager` seems like an obvious choice. To enable the processing of the `@Transactional` annotation, you can either use `@EnableTransactionManagement` or the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` namespace. Both are explained in the Javadoc of [`@EnableTransactionManagement`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html)

By default, a runtime exception thrown from that annotated method will manage a transaction rollback. If your code is using checked exceptions, you'll have to configure the `rollbackFor` attribute of the annotation.

There are more details and examples available [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)